# Count string character mvvm

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to show string in textblock with the right fontsize according to length of my string, so i think maybe by counting string length or character and then updating my font size , but I have no idea how to do that in code....

Answer (score 1):

```
    <Style x:Key="ApplicationNameStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
         <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding FontSize,Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource Sampe}}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Effect">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" Opacity="0.25" ShadowDepth="0"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Viewmodel.cs

```
public Double FontSize
{
    get
    {
         return _fontSize;
    }
    set
    {
        _fontSize = value;
        put your logic!
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FontSize"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Either the binding, or the property name is wrong. Both should refer the same property (either `FontSize12` or `FontSize1`)

Comment: Yes modified the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Converter` like this

```
public class TextFontSizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int size;
        //value is MyText
        //Your logic to calculate the font size;
        ...
        return size;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In the view, declare the converter in the resources section:

```
<local:TextFontSizeConverter x:Key="Converter"/>
```

Then, bind the it to the `TextBlock`

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="{Binding MyText, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}" />
```

With this solution, you can always re-use the logic with any TextBlock.